# Asp.net mvc Html.ActionLink doesnt work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Rss",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{SourceSite}/{Name}",
            defaults: new { controller = "RssController", action = "Index", SourceSite = UrlParameter.Optional, Name = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

public class RssController : Controller
{
    // GET: Rss
    public ActionResult Index(string SourceSite, string Name)
    {
        string Url = NewsResourses.common.Single(p => p.SourceSite == SourceSite & p.Name == Name).Url;
        var rssItems = GetItemsFromChannel(Url);
        ViewBag.SourceName = Name;
        return View(rssItems);
    }
```

but when i am trying to get something like localhost:port/RssController/Index/Ria/Politics
i get a 404 http exception.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Your url shouldn't contain 'controller' more like this : localhost:4000/rss/index

Comment: Ok, thank you. Thats work :)

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to specify the `Controller` part of the control name. Try the below:

```
defaults: new { controller = "Rss", action = "Index", SourceSite = UrlParameter.Optional, Name = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do:

```
localhost:port/Rss/Index/Ria/Politics
```